# Android: RTL support - digits embedded in a right to left sentence (Hebrew)

Tags: android, hebrew, right-to-left

My application displays Hebrew text which comes from a Web Service.
When a sentence contains digits (in the middle of it), the digits appear in a mirror view:
29 appears as 92, 21:45 appears as 54:12 and 2,000 appears as 000,2.
Also, when a sentence starts with digits or English characters, they get thrown to the end of the sentence messing it all up...

Does anyone have an idea how can this be solved? Is RTL support in Android still immature?

Comment: [sorry for the late reply]

This is a known issue. 

Note that the official Hebrew devices do NOT display this problem. If you have a device that was sold by an israely cell operator (cellcom, pelephone, orange) than everything would work properly. If you are using a device to which you just "pushed" hebrew fonts than you would get this problem. We had 

AFAIK there is no workaround, but if you do find one please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is RTL support in Android still
>   immature?

If by "immature" you mean "nonexistent", then, yes, it is immature. Each [Android SDK release](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html) lists the supported languages, and you will notice that RTL languages are not among them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, there is nothing that can be done? no workaround? I mean, there are devices with Hebrew interface which have been customized by local carriers and applications do display Hebrew (to some extent)...

Comment: I am not aware of a general-purpose workaround short of substantial firmware modifications. There has been somewhat greater discussion of this issue *vis a vis* Arabic, so you might want to search the official Android Google Groups for "Arabic" and see if those posts give you any ideas.

Comment: OK, much obliged for your attention.

Answer (score 5):

Try presenting your text in a webkit control, its RTL support works fine, as long as the HTML code is tagged appropriately.

Comment: holy frickin cow.. +1 for lateral thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Forward to 2015 - those issues are gone, and the answer marked as correct is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/). I'd very much like to know which commit has the fix exactly