# Displaying inverse numbers when loading Hebrew rss with android ...

Tags: android, xml, feed, hebrew, right-to-left

I'm Loading an Hebrew (rtl) xml feed with xml Dom using eclipse android environment.

When displaying the feed on TextView text is OK but numbers Displaying inverse

for example :

if feed (XML) contain 007 it WILL displayed as 700..

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-posting my own answer:

"Try presenting your text in a webkit control, its RTL support works fine, as long as the HTML code is tagged appropriately."

Hope that helps you too.

Comment: Hi VitalyB,

I tried use the webview if that what you meant when you said "webkit control"

I changed the textview to webview and set the html encoding

String stext= "<html><body>שלום <b>007</b> points.</body></html>";

I tried this
webview.loadData(stext, "text/html", "utf-8");

and this 
webview.loadData(stext, "text/html", "windows-1255");

but still didn't solve it and getting a gibberish text now  ..

any helped will blessed..

thanks

Comment: Hey Zohar, I never actually did it myself but a friend said it worked great for him. I'll try to ask his help for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Android doesn't officially support RTL languages.

Have a look here: [Android: RTL support - digits embedded in a right to left sentence (Hebrew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584245/android-rtl-support-digits-embedded-in-a-right-to-left-sentence-hebrew)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to reply to the comments on @Vitalyb's answer, but I have used this solution and it works great. You just need to use a webview, and load it with html text. There are plenty of code samples available on the Android dev sites.

Comment: Thanks @eli & @VitalyB for your replay's I tried use the webview but I keep getting gibberish text tried both utf-8 and windows-1255 but it didn't help,this is how it look like:

http://images.wave-site.com/jib.jpg

thanks

Comment: OK ,Thanks that solve it (: just need to add:

"<body style=\"text-align:right;direction:rtl;\"> "+ mytext + ""</body>

Answer (score 0):

my final solution was:

add a charset=utf-8

```
public static String BuildHtml(String _HtmlString)
{       
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;
            charset=utf-8\">");
    sb.append("<body style=\"direction:rtl;\">");
    sb.append(_HtmlString.trim());
    sb.append("</body>");
    sb.append("</html>");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

then calling it just before loadData..

```
 myWebview.loadData(BuildHtml(mytext), "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I will glad to hear about (light) simple solution then that,for using a TextView instead of WebView..

thanks

http://www.wave-site.com/